# Why did I get this exception when running JPA?

Tags: java, maven, jpa

This is just a normal JPA console built by Maven. I got a very annoying exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
```

I found some solutions about that such problem and they suggest adding ***javaee-api*** lib to pom.xml. But the error still stands with ***javee-api lib***.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // This line causes error
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
                    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
        // It works when I comment above line and print hello
    }
}
```

So I'm pretty sure that the exception doesn't relate to library issues and the persistence.xml file might cause the problem.

Here my project tree

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── hoan
    │   │           ├── App.java
    │   │           └── Customer.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── META-INF
    │           └── persistence.xml
    └── test
```

My persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="testjpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>

    <class>com.foo.Customer</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
                  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quickstart">
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.22</version>
</dependency>
```

By the way I followed this thread ["No Persistence provider for EntityManager" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261435/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-error) which has exactly same my problem, but nothing seems to work.

What's the problem?

Updated: the command line to run jar file

```
java -cp target/jpa-demo.jar com.foo.App
```

Comment: "So I'm pretty sure that the exception doesn't relate to library issues and the persistence.xml file might cause the problem." - I'm pretty sure you'd be wrong. There's really only one way I know of a `ClassNotFoundError` being caused, and that's by the class not being available anywhere on your classpath. Check the WAR that your build creates, look at the JARs it puts into `WEB-INF/lib/`, and whether `Persistence.class` really is in them? If it's a console app, how are you running it?

Comment: In the eclipse I can invoke those such classes without any errors, so I think the nessesary libs were fully loaded

Comment: That's not really conclusive. How is your actual program being run? As in, literally, what's the command line used to execute `java`?

Comment: @Millimoose +1. Eclipse has it's own meta-model; much different from Maven, a lot happens behind the scenes. I advise against pointing to Eclipse for backup in "this should work". Does it compile, when you run `mvn clean install` from command line?

Answer (score 1):

Add the missing dependency to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Why is it running within eclipse ?

I'm not an eclipse addict, but I know that you can easily customize your classpath and it is not kept synchronized with your pom file. So there are good chances that the classpath used by eclipse don't match the maven classpath.

Answer (score 0):

add this jar into build path [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax/javax.persistence.jar.zip)

although its better to add dependency through maven like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Regards
Anshul